# Store custom Listener (interface) in Bundle onSaveInstance (orientation change)

Tags: java, android, interface, listener, bundle

I have a main fragment that starts a DialogFragment and sets a Listener (Interface defined in DialogFragment) via "setOnOptionClickListener(interface OnOptionClickListener)".

How do I store this in onSaveInstance of setOnOptionClickListener ?

*Accessing methods of the listener passed by MainFragment inside the DialogFragment throws a NullPointerException after orientation change.*

The following code is a stripped down version of the original.

**In MainFragment**

```
private void showDialog(){ 

    CustomDialogFragment dialog = new CustomDialogFragment();

    dialog.setOnOptionClickListener(new OnOptionClickListener(){

        //Overwrite some methods

    });

    dialog.show(getChildFragmentManager(), "optionsdialog");
}
```

**In CustomDialogFragment**

```
public class CustomDialogFragment extends DialogFragment {   

public interface OnOptionClickListener{
    ArrayList<String> getData();
    void onDone();
}    

private ArrayList<String> data = new ArrayList<String>();

public void setOnOptionClickListener(OnOptionClickListener mListener){
   this.mListener = mListener;
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {


   ... do some stuff ...

   //Accessing the Listener!

   data = mListener.getData();
   /* I could save the ArrayList in onSaceInstanceState Bundle Argument
      But how do I save the call to the listener with the method that MainFragment 
      overwrote and passed as argument (setOnOptionClickListener()...) ?? */

   mListener.onDone();
}
}
```

Comment: Found workaround accessing the listener object in MainFragment from inside the DialogFragment using 

`((MainFragment) getParentFragment()).getListener();`

where getListener() returns the listener object.